# How do I show the menubar items even without mouse over?

Tags: 16.04, menu, lts, appmenu

How do I show the menu items for an app without requiring my cursor to be over over the application's menu bar in the Panel? I want it always shown. I am running the 64-bit version of the Ubuntu 16 LTS

Comment: Did you check your "appearance" settings?

Comment: Sorry, the Settings kept crashing when I was trying to open it but it finally worked after a few reboots and I've fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`System Settings > Appearance > Behavior`

Under `Show the menus for a window` select `In the window's title bar`

Comment: Thanks! I just saw it and as I said on my comment above, the Settings kept crashing when I try to open it but finally worked after a few reboots.

Comment: OK, I'll leave this here in case anyone comes along with the same question.

Comment: Yeah I have to wait a few more minutes before I can accept this as answer.